# How can I perform Forgot Password on Microsoft Azure B2c on React App?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, azure-ad-msal

I'm trying to implement Microsoft Azure B2c on React App as single page app. But PublicClientApplication is not recognizable. Anyone

```js
import { loginRequest, msalConfig } from "../../authConfig";

import msal from "msal";
const myMSALObj = new msal.PublicClientApplication(msalConfig);
```

Error:

TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'PublicClientApplication')
at Module. (Login.tsx:19:1)
at ./src/pages/Login/Login.tsx (Login.tsx:134:1)
at **webpack_require** (bootstrap:856:1)
at fn (bootstrap:150:1) {componentStack: '\n    at Lazy\n    at Route (http://localhost:3000/s…ost:3000/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js:86026:5)'}

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BJVCT.png)

Comment: Based on the [docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/msal#usage) I think you ought to import it like this `import * as Msal from "msal";`

Comment: Okay, but it won't work.